# Cart page sub total label

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, ce-1.9.2.2

Using Magento 1.9.2.2

I want to change **Sub Total Label(Just label)** everywhere...

I found that it's coming from

```
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/tax/checkout/subtotal.phtml
```

From this line

```
<td style="<?php echo $this->getStyle() ?>" class="a-right" colspan="<?php echo $this->getColspan(); ?>">
    <?php echo $this->getTotal()->getTitle() ?>
</td>
```

I've checked

```
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Address/Total/Subtotal.php
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Block/Order/Totals.php
```

But not coming from both above files... so from where it can be coming?

Comment: have you check Mage_Sales_Block_Order_Totals::_initTotals() ;  $this->_totals['subtotal'] = new Varien_Object(array(
            'code'  => 'subtotal',
            'value' => $source->getSubtotal(),
            'label' => $this->__('Subtotal')
        ));

Comment: app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Block/Order/Totals.php

Comment: Let me check both

Comment: You can also use Translate inline to change lable. it will be easy way.

Comment: No it's not coming from app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Block/Order/Totals.php and also from protected function _initTotals()

Comment: @kul: I don't think it's proper way to do so, I mean I don't want to translate I just want to change full label

Comment: Please check i have added answer hope it's work for you.

Comment: Yes thanks  @Keshar , I'll try your answer and will let you know in sometime.

Comment: it is flabbergasting, checking this in 2017 and indeed that totals block is one place where translation doesn't kick in. These words should technically be run through the sales and tax translation files, but they don't.
I have managed to change "shipping" to "delivery" everywhere but not in these blocks. Translation not applied. Grrr!

Answer (score 0):

I know this point is a little old but i recently had to solve this problem.

The easiest solution for my needs was to rewrite the

`Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart_Totals` class and override the `renderTotals` function.

Path of File:

```
app\code\core\Mage\Checkout\Block\Cart\Totals.php
```

Override To:

```
app\code\local\Mage\Checkout\Block\Cart\Totals.php
```

It ended up looking something like this:

```
public function renderTotals($area = null, $colspan = 1)
{
    return $this->_replaceLabels(parent::renderTotals($area, $colspan));
}

protected function _replaceLabels($html){
    $labelMap = array();
    $labelMap['Subtotal'] = "Product Total";
    $labelMap['Grand Total'] = "Order Total";
    $labelMap["Shipping & Handling"] = "Shipping";

    foreach($labelMap as $key => $value){
        $html = str_replace($key, $value,$html) ;
    }
    return $html;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to solve very similar question for Mage 1.9.

How exactly did you overridden `Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart_Totals`? Did you have to change `config.xml`? In what way?

My Magento refuse to let me override, it simply ignores my changes.